# Unauthorized request handling in Angular.js with Box API v2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, box-api, box, boxapiv2

I am developing a web app with angular.js v1.5.7, which integrates Box Services using oauth2 authentication on the client-side to retrive the tokens for accessing the API.

I have a problem when the access token expires. I make a request with the expired token, and I receive a 401 (unauthorized) response that I can't catch in Angular because the response has a status code of -1.  This happens before I am able to catch this response in a $httpsInterceptor.

I made a repository in GitHub to demonstrate this behavior `https://github.com/danyfu/box-api-test`, it's an express server that serves the 3000 port the Angular app.

In the Angular app, it's only a button you click to request to the API to GET the root folder of the user:

```
https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0?fields=id,name,type,item_status,size,item_collection,shared_link
```

With the request I add the access token.

When I make the request with the invalid token, the response returns two error logs.
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wphMY.png)

When I make the request with a valid access token, it retrieves the folder info and a status of 200.
[Correct Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdvl4.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can use passport-box which will do the oauth flow in your app.

https://github.com/bluedge/passport-box

Here's an example where I use it as well:

https://github.com/kendomen/boxadmin